# Record Lock not released even after completion of apex transaction in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience

I have created a custom lightning component to do mass update of Opportunity Lines. I have added that component as tab against the Opportunity. When i do mass update of Opportunity lines and it is finished successfully. I return to opportunity header detail page in the same session and try to edit the opportunity header fields and save the Opportunity. It throws error that edit is performed in the session please reload the page to update the opportunity header.
Since mass update transaction is already complete lock should have been released 
I also have not locked explicitly inside my apex code. Does anybody know if this is known SFDC issue or how to fix this without refreshing the page

sample code - Apex COntroller class

```
public class LtngUpdateLines{

@AuraEnabled
public static void MassUpdateLines(Id recordId)
{
list<OpportunityLineItem> lstlines = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
list<OpportunityLineItem> lines = [select Id,quantity from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = :recordId];

if (lines.size() > 0)
{
    for (opportunityLineItem o1:lines)
    {
        o1.quantity = 888;
       lstlines.add(o1);
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] sv1 = Database.Update(lstlines,false);

}



}


}
```

---

Lightning Component controller

---

```
({
    updateLines : function(component, event, helper) {
         var action = component.get('c.MassUpdateLines');

      // pass the apex method parameters to action 
      action.setParams({
         'recordId' : component.get("v.recordId")
      });
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         //store state of response
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //set response value in list of line items attribute on component.
           alert('Inside success');
         }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);    
    }
})
```

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you know how to resolve this without refreshing page?

Comment: Can you add code snippets or minimum viable code to reproduce this

Comment: i had raised case with salesforce.com. salesforce suggested that i may be having some process builder running or batch job scheduled with my user. pseudo code is as follows.

Comment: create a lightning component with html table to show Opportunity product lines. Add a button mass update lines. select few lines using checkbox and update quantity or price or servicedate simple update using database.update. Add lightning component to custom tab in Opportunity.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue in dev org as well. issue occurs if i do updates more than once in the same session without navigating to any other tab. If i hit mass update and lines are updated first time, i am able to update oppty header details but if i hit mass update button for second time i am unable to update oppty header without refreshing the page

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Please refer to code snippets added above. if you need any other info. please let me know

Comment: This is not a row locking error and has nothing to do with transaction boundaries. The system is trying to prevent the user from inadvertently overwriting backend changes.

Comment: @DavidReed i am updating opportunity lines using code and from UI i am trying to update opportunity header. how updating header will result in wrongly updating lines? i am updating one text field on opportunity header

Comment: this is not row locking error but the behaviour is part of collision detection security implemented by salesforce in order to keep the data integrity in place. but why salesforce is preventing me to update the oppty header

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Do you think that this is salesforce.com issue a bug in salesforce.com